# Extractict the content betwin div tags with DOM but keepeng al other html tags

Tags: php, html, dom

I whant to extract the content betwin the tags from html file with DOM.

source file:

```
<html>
<body>
some html code
..........
<div id="text"> 
<p>some title</p> <br>
<p>some text</p> <br>
<img src="../images2/somegif.gif">
<div>
..........
</body>
</html>
```

my code:

```
$file = 'somefile.html';
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($file);
$text = $html->getElementById('text');

echo $text;
```

the result is:

```
<div id="text"> 
<p>some title</p> <br>
<p>some text</p> <br>
<img src="../images2/somegif.gif">
<div>
```

What I want is just the data inside the div tags but keeping all the other HTML elements like:

```
<p>some title</p> <br>
<p>some text</p> <br>
<img src="../images2/somegif.gif">
```

How can I do that? ...I need that data to send to a mysql DB later on. Thank you.

Comment: $text = $html->find('div[id=text]'); echo $text->innertext; http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I did: $text = $html->find('div[id=text]'); $text =  $text->innertext; echo $text; ...but Iget this errror:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in......

Answer (score 0):

```
$text1= $html->getElementById('text');
$text= $text1->innertext;
echo $text;
```

I just change the var names  ...LOL